# AWS - STS how to use AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder with global region

Tags: aws-sts

I used the

```
AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient sts_client = new AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient(),
```

and a default region (Global) was set authomatically. But this constructor is deprcated and the recommendation is to use:

```
AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder.
```

I want it to use a default region, as well. I wrote:

```
AWSSecurityTokenService stsClient = AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCredentials)).build();
```

but I got an exception:

```
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to find a region via the region provider chain. Must provide an explicit region in the builder or setup environment to supply a region.

at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder.setRegion(AwsClientBuilder.java:371)
at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder.configureMutableProperties(AwsClientBuilder.java:337)
at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsSyncClientBuilder.build(AwsSyncClientBuilder.java:46)
at co.softimize.STSManager.<init>(STSManager.java:31)
at co.softimize.sts.STSManagerTests.setup(STSManagerTests.java:40)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I've never heard of the Global region, but to specify a default region with the new non-deprecated Builder method, you can use:

`.withRegion(Regions.DEFAULT_REGION)`

So your command would be:

`AWSSecurityTokenService stsClient = AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder.standard()
.withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCredentials))
.withRegion(Regions.DEFAULT_REGION.getName())
.build();`

FYI - in my version of the Regions enum, `DEFAULT_REGION` is `US_WEST_2`. Don't forget to

`import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;`

EDIT: It may be useful to know that it doesn't matter what region you specify. The generated STS credentials can be used in all regions (so they are 'global' in a sense).